# Does it make sense to have both link and controller on a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

From what I've gathered, `link` deals with dom manipulation while `controller` deals with directive specific logic. So does it make sense to have both `link` and `controller` with a directive? Since `compile` returns `link`, what about `compile` and `controller` used together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the number of directive that i have seen here is something that seems to be common

You implement controller if you want to expose an API for your directive. This API is used to control the directive. When directives take dependencies on other directives using `require`, what gets injected is a controller instance.
When dealing with forms we see `FormController` and `NgModelController`  which are good examples of directive controllers.

For most of the other cases `link` function used.

For small cases if we need to do DOM manipulation `compile` can be used